# partial least squares with two dependent variables, one continuous and the other binary

Tags: binary-data, continuous-data, partial-least-squares

I can do use [pls2](https://www.r-bloggers.com/pls2-with-r/) to predict multiple dependent variables from a matrix of predictor variables at once as follows:

```
library(pls)
sensory0 <- cbind(green = oliveoil$sensory[,'green'], syrup = oliveoil$sensory[,'syrup'])
oliveoil0 <- list(chemical = oliveoil$chemical, sensory = sensory0)
oopls0 <- pls::mvr(sensory ~chemical, data = oliveoil0, method = 'simpls', validation = 'LOO')
summary(oopls0)
```

> ```
>    Data:  X dimension: 16 5 
>           Y dimension: 16 2 Fit method: simpls Number of components considered: 5
>
>    VALIDATION: RMSEP Cross-validated using 16 leave-one-out segments.
>
>    Response: green 
>                 (Intercept)  1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps
>    CV           24.26    23.87    20.51    21.35    23.96    28.38
>    adjCV        24.26    23.79    20.41    21.20    23.70    27.98
>
>    Response: syrup 
>             (Intercept)  1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps 
>    CV           3.166    2.134    2.319    2.476    2.937    3.066 
>    adjCV        3.166    2.128    2.304    2.456    2.899    3.021
>
>    TRAINING: % variance explained
>
>    1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps 
>    X        99.59    99.87   100.00   100.00   100.00
>    green    11.69    43.64    45.39    48.52    48.66
>    syrup    57.65    58.80    58.80    58.81    62.39
> ```

This ends up suggesting that I use two latent variables, and that we end up predicting about 44% of the variability in green and 59% of the variability in syrup.

What if though, one of the two y variables is a binary variable?

```
medsplit <- function(x){as.numeric(x > median(x))}
sensory2 <- cbind(green = oliveoil$sensory[,'green'], syrup = medsplit(oliveoil$sensory[,'syrup']))
oliveoil2 <- list(chemical = oliveoil$chemical, sensory = sensory2)
```

> ```
> Data:     X dimension: 16 5
>           Y dimension: 16 2 
> Fit method: simpls 
> Number of components considered: 5
>
> VALIDATION: RMSEP Cross-validated using 16 leave-one-out segments.
>
> Response: green 
>        (Intercept)  1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps 
> CV           24.26    23.86    20.51    21.35    23.96    28.38
> adjCV        24.26    23.79    20.41    21.20    23.70    27.98
>
> Response: syrup 
>          (Intercept)  1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps
>  CV          0.5333   0.4299   0.4251   0.4315   0.5002   0.5267 
>  adjCV       0.5333   0.4288   0.4233   0.4293   0.4952   0.5208
>
> TRAINING: % variance explained
>          1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps 
> X        99.59    99.87   100.00   100.00   100.00 
> green    11.70    43.64    45.39    48.52    48.66 
> syrup    37.79    45.74    47.38    47.46    47.78
> ```

In this case, it looks like I am getting out a similar answer and we predict about the same variance in "green" and slightly less than before with the categorical variable for "syrup". Is this a reasonable approach? Alternatively, do I need to do something to more explicitly handle the binary y variable?

I see the `plsRglm` package does have an option for logistic PLS, but it seems to only handles one dependent variable rather than several. I suppose I could run two models, one to predict the binary variable and one to predict the continuous one. I prefer this pls-2 approach though for interpretability, since it shows how y variables together get predicted by x varaibles together, although maybe that's not a sufficient reason.

Thoughts? I guess my central question here is: What is the best way to use pls to approach a mix of binary and continuous variables?

Comment: PLS2 is not a very common way to go. It is generally used for classification and when the response variables are correlated. If that is not the case, PLS1 is very likely to perform better since you get to choose different number of components for each response and this approach usually yields a model with higher predictive power.

Comment: Fair point. This points to a shortcoming of my example that I posted here. I have two actual problems with data I shoudn't post:  In problem 1 
 the response variablesare not  correlated, but have a similar relationship to the predictor variables. Cross-validation suggests suggest one latent variable and when the model predicts high levels of variable y1 they also predict low levels of variable y2. I like PLS2 in this case because it seems to suggest a way in which my x varaibles seem to have common effect on my y variables.

Comment: In a second case, I have a handful of y variables, some discrete and some continuous, that are indeed correlated. I'd like to take advantage of pls-2's ability to handle correlated y predictors in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing some ideas:

Let's say your categorical variable whose name is Cat has 4 levels: A, B, C, D.
And you have 1 continuous variable whose name is Cont

I would create response matrix to be used in PLS2 such that for 3 samples: (first line is headers)

```
A B C D Cont
- - - - ----
1 0 0 0 4.2
0 1 0 0 3.3
0 0 0 1 1.9
```

So the first sample has A as categorical response and 4.2 as continous response and so on. You can apply PLS2 to this response matrix.

For prediction, you can assign categorical variable as whichever the maximum of A, B, C, D prediction is.

**Edit:** I forgot that your discrete variable is binary. Then you have only A and B and same logic applies to your case too.

Comment: Thanks! So in this case, the approach that I used in my question would be appropriate, right? It seems then that I don't have to do anything special besides putting binary variables as ones and zeros in the response matrix.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is the best way. But I would surely give it a shot.